# addClass to Select tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use JS to apply an active class to a selected option.

The unselected a items are {display:none} by default.

https://jsfiddle.net/charliedemko/pLm17zmp/1/

```
<style>
    .selecthidden {display:none;}
    .selectactive {display:block !important;}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#studioselect option').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass(selectactive);
            $.not(this).removeClass(selectactive);
    });
    });
</script>

<select id="studioselect">
  <option value="select studio">Select Studio</option>
  <option value="neutral bay">Neutral Bay</option>
  <option value="manly">Manly</option>
  <option value="bondi junction">Bondi Junction</option>
  <option value="bondi beach">Bondi Beach</option>
  <option value="south melbourne">South Melbourne</option>
  <option value="fitzroy">Fitzroy</option>
  <option value="north perth">North Perth</option>
  <option value="myaree">Myaree</option>
  <option value="wellington">Wellington</option>
</select>
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
<a id="button-neutralbay" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Neautral Bay</a>
<a id="button-manly" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Manly</a>
<a id="button-bondijunction" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Bondi Junction</a>
<a id="button-bondibeach" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Bondi Beach</a>
<a id="button-southmelbourne" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >South Melbourne</a>
<a id="button-fitzroy" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Fitzroy</a>
<a id="button-northperth" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >North Perth</a>
<a id="button-myaree" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Myaree</a>
<a id="button-wellington" class="qbutton selecthidden" href="#" >Wellington</a>
</div>
```

All help appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: You want to show the link corresponding to the selected option?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. It adds `selectactive`.

Comment: **Missing Quotes:** The class name should be wrapped in quotes. `$(this).addClass(selectactive);` ==> `$(this).addClass("selectactive");`

Comment: [To show the corresponding link of the selected option.](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9w4hnd7x/)

Comment: Thanks Tushar.. really appreciated. Your JS Fiddle works perfectly.. I'm adding that to my site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following in order to achieve what you are asking in simple way :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#studioselect').change(function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
                $('#unhide').html('<a id="button-'+val+'" class="qbutton selectactive" href="#" >'+val+'</a>');
            })
        });
    </script>

    <select id="studioselect">
        <option value="select studio">Select Studio</option>
        <option value="neutral bay">Neutral Bay</option>
        <option value="manly">Manly</option>
        <option value="bondi junction">Bondi Junction</option>
        <option value="bondi beach">Bondi Beach</option>
        <option value="south melbourne">South Melbourne</option>
        <option value="fitzroy">Fitzroy</option>
        <option value="north perth">North Perth</option>
        <option value="myaree">Myaree</option>
        <option value="wellington">Wellington</option>
    </select>
    <div id="unhide"></div>
```